# Laravel specific format random string

Tags: laravel

how can I create random string in `Laravel` like this

```
df5bd363-7bb3-4ab7-bc51-92a377e9bfda&VstCode=27621521869
```

I need the dashes and the '&VstCode=' not dynamic and fixed in every string generated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first part of the string looks and smells like an `UUID`. The latter part, i would just hardcode. There could be an argument that the query params should be handled by either an URL builder, Guzzle or similar. But in practical terms, i would solve your problem like this in most cases.

```
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;   

public function generateString() {
    return Uuid::uuid4() . '&VstCode=27621521869';
}
```

---

I ran this code in `tinker`, it provided the following result.

```
386da289-0655-46ac-adc4-9cc54583cd22&VstCode=27621521869
```